# C# Ввод данных в чужое приложение с помощью Win32 Api

Tags: c#, winapi, ввод

Есть приложение написанное на Win32, у него есть текст бокс, как можно ввсети туда данные?
Ниже скрин информация полученная с помощью ShoWin 2.00
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через WinAPI SendMessage.
Пример тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083954/send-message-in-c-sharp
Нужно будет отправлять команды по типу кликнуть мышкой по тем-то координатам (textbox), и подобным образом передавать ввод с клавиатуры.
Но можно попробовать упороться и на основе WinAPI функций, предлагаемых в ответе: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014544/read-a-non-c-sharp-apps-textbox-using-windows-api-from-a-c-sharp-windows-forms-a реализовать более прямой ввод.

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin в ответе есть описание, ссылки не выходят за пределы домена.